# Where to see the logs for a failed deployment on managed Vms on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, gcloud

The deployment fails on google app engine when I try to deploy my app on managed VMs. I suspect it's because appengine doesn't manage to run my container because it has an error. However, I can't check the docker logs since the container failed to run. Locally it works because it has a different config than in production. I suspect that in production my app doesn't resolve the db server ip in the local network but I don't have any logs to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Google Developer Console - Compute - VM Instances. SSH into the instance you would like to inspect.

When in web SSH console, see logs in the `/var/log/app_engine/app/`. I found our java app errors in the `/var/log/app_engine/app/STDOUT.yyyy_mm_dd.log`.

Comment: If the instance doesn't come up I think it gets removed, so this won't actually work.

Comment: You think or you know?

Comment: I *think*. I've never been able to successfully log in to an instance belonging to a botched deployment. The option to switch it to user managed isn't there while the spinner shows, and so SSHing into it is not an option then. Once the deployment truly fails, the instances go away. That said, I still say *think* because app engine is very much a black box, and I might be missing something. If you have further details, please do share.

Comment: When deploying a java app, it's possible to create an app package that breaks on startup (e.g. it is missing a class/package), resulting in an inoperable JVM/servlet/app due to the exception, while the docker image is up and seems ok. This isn't technically a "failed deployment", because the deploy runs ok, the instance shows in console, albeit it gets restarted every 3-4 minutes due to failed healthchecks (depends on your healthcheck settings).

Comment: The kicker is that the error does not show in the normal GAE logs, you need to follow the procedure above. You might want to disable healthechecks to prevent restarts, while you inspect the logs (although AFAIK this does not happen once you switch the instance to user-managed).

Comment: Sounds like it might be different for managed VMs then. From what I can tell, if the process in the container dies, and subsequent restarts (including, it seems, new instances created) don't work, then the whole thing just goes away. I s'pose that's what you get for dealing with beta software..

Comment: My point is: if there is an exception thrown while loading the app, then this will result in an inoperable JVM, with the exception not showing in normal GAE logs (it seems the log collection needs a functioning JVM). However, the logs mentioned in the answer will properly show the exception, giving you clues how to fix it.

Comment: Right, but if the vm instance is removed altogether there's no recourse at all. This is the behavior I've seen with managed VMs, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If your instance fails to come up there should also be a crash.log in the developer console:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/[yourproject]/logs

There should be a dropdown saying `Request`. If you click it you should be able to see crash.log and syslog and some others. There you can often find a hint of the underlying problem.

However, in my own project that dropdown is broken since yesterday, so I'm not sure if it will work for you. We're currently waiting for Google to fix that.

Comment: It's currently working again in our Managed VM project.